# Node.js EventEmitter function error `listener must be a function` when `typeof` returns function - could be scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have an object which is being interacted with from a few different node.js modules.

I want to have some of these modules be able to add eventListeners to the object.

I have an `events` file where the event emitters are attached and removed. It looks basically like this

```
    function onData() {
        if(!this._eventEmitter) this._eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
        this._eventEmitter.on('data', this._callback);
    }


    function removeOn() {
        console.log(typeof this._callback, this._callback.name);
        try {
         this._eventEmitter.removeListener('data', this._callback.name);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('err', e);
        }
    }

module.exports = {
     on: onData, 
     off; removeOn
}
```

I'm adding event listeners pretty simply through just

```
var evt = require('./libs/events');

// a bunch of stuff
function fctName(){ 
   console.log('this is the callback');
};
this._callback = fctName;

evt.on.call(this);

var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
  evt.off.call(self);
},3000);
```

The `on` method fires perfectly on queue. When I try to remove the listener with the `off` method, the console shows `function fctName` showing that `this._callback` is in fact a function and the name is known. But the `try` fails and the error returned is `[TypeError: listener must be a function]`.

I thought the issue might have been the scope of the function not being available, but the function should be attached to the `this` object which is being passed around. I'm kind of at my wits end with this.

---------------- Update ----------------------------

I've removed the `.name` from `this._callback` in removeListener as @bergi recommended. I no longer get the error, but the listener is still not removed.

I've also tried

```
this._eventEmitter.removeAllListeners('data');
this._eventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
```

neither of which removed the listener.

The console output of `this._eventEmitter` is

```
 { domain: null,
  _events: { data: [Function: fctName] },
  _maxListeners: 10 }
```

I can clearly see the `data` and `fctName` of the function I'm trying to remove, but cannot remove it in any way.

Comment: You're missing a `.`, in `this_callback.name`. A 5K user should know better than to ask these questions on the site. Sorry.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Everyone can make a mistake and overlook typoes - independent from their rep points. The only expectation is that a 5K user will known when to delete his posts :-)

Comment: @Bergi, do you mean I should delete this post? Or I shouldn't have deleted the last one? I'm not at 5K yet, so maybe I gain all this knowledge when I hit that point :-)

Comment: @pedalpete: I don't know any last one… Yes, you may delete it, it would be closed as "typo error, not helpful to others" eventually and then automatically deleted after some time anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, the typo was a typo in cleaning up the question. The question is still valid. removeListener is still not removing the

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed that. Right, I'll answer it…

Answer (score 2):

`removeListener` expects the callback itself, not it's [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Only the first parameter, the event name, is supposed to be a string, the second one should be the function.

```
function removeOn() {
    this._eventEmitter.removeListener('data', this._callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi, for some reason I was sure I had seen other questions that said to use the name, but it looks like they were only saying use a named function. I had tried without the name, and I don't get an error, but I also don't get the listener removed (as in the listeners function is still being